# How to merge 2 edges?

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh, objects, edit-mode

I am new to modeling. I was trying to make something but couldn't find a way to merge the [image: Here you can see the edges are separate]edges of two shapes. Below are some pictures of the object. I have tried bridging edge loops but it didn't work as the edge is in different parts. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can merge two edges by merging their vertices. You can do this by changing the selection mode to vertex, selecting two vertices, and going to menu *Mesh > Merge* and there you will see some options depending on what you need. Also you can use the shortcut <kbd>M</kbd>. Hope this helps and happy modelling!

[image: Image showing the menu layout]

Comment: I have tried that it doesn't work...have a look at the image I've attached